# Bachelor's degree and Master's degree, but why PhD degree?

Tags: punctuation

Why do we say PhD degree instead of **PhD's** degree?

Are there any apostrophe forms available for PhD degree, like can we say doctor's degree?

Comment: Does [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=PhD+degree%2C+doctor%27s+degree%2C+doctoral+degree&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although a PhD is a *doctor of philosophy* it is the name of the qualification or degree, not the title of the person who holds it. The title used by someone with a PhD is most commonly just 'Doctor'.

Remember that, in this context, the term "philosophy" does not refer to the field or academic discipline of philosophy. It just denotes a  higher academic level in whatever field of study the person has undertook. Calling someone "a doctor of philosophy" could therefore be misleading.

'Doctor's degree', 'doctorate', and 'doctoral degree' are all interchangeable and again refer to the qualification, not the person holding it.

In my experience, people *don't* say "PhD degree" as you suggest - they just say things like "he has a PhD". But, given that a PhD is a *type* of degree, I can't say it's wrong to do so.

Comment: Given people say ["I am studying for a master's degree,"](https://www.quora.com/Which-one-is-correct-I-am-doing-a-masters-degree-or-I-am-studying-for-a-masters-degree) I want to make sure "I am studying for a PhD degree" is correct.

Comment: @Gqqnbig One doesn't study for a Phd. One does a Phd. And we simply do not say "Phd. degree" as Astralbee has already said. Also, we say: I am doing a Master's in [field] and I'm doing a Phd. in [field]. The formal term: to earn a Phd. in [field] but not in the progressive tense: He earned a Phd. in physics at Yale University in [year].